# Consolidated task list

Tags: tasks, task-list

How to create a consolidated task list containing all the (task)list items within the site collection(including the subsites).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a list, but a search result:

You can use Content By Search Webpart for this (SP 2013 and SP Online).

In the Query you should put:

```
path:{YOUR SITE COLLECTION URL}* ContentTypeId:0x0108*
```

for example

```
path:http://portal.com/sites/thesite* ContentTypeId:0x0108*
```

A more complete guide is found [here](http://yalla.itgroove.net/2013/02/roll-up-sharepoint-2013-tasks-with-content-search-web-part/).

If not in SharePoint 2013 or Online, you would most likely have to use the normal Search Results webpart, with a Search Scope that identifies only tasks in your site collection, or write some nice webpart yourself with a [Cross List Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.crosslistquerycache(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Robert for your response. I'm on SP2010 standard edition.Are there anyways that i can achieve this OOB or by using any scripts?

Comment: OK, here is more details for creating custom WP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192318/sharepoint-2010-aggregate-tasks-across-sites